# PC Specifications for a small DFT Research Group

Tags: quantum-chemistry, high-performance-computing

Planning to set up a small research group here at my university to do some DFT/MD work and I'm looking for a nice setup that will cater to that. Will be asking for funding from the university or from a local government agency. Any suggestion for PC or cluster specifications that will be bang for buck? We're hoping to start with some novel materials research like with lead-free hybrid perovskites and moving on to other endeavors such as doing theoretical sensing studies.

Comment: Related post: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/

Comment: What is the budget range, and how many group members will there be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggestions on personal computers for matter modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/suggestions-on-personal-computers-for-matter-modeling)

Comment: @NikeDattani - Small group, 2 to 3 people for now, including me. Initial funding might just be 3k to 5k USD. So I guess that's small of a budget for a cluster, so I guess specs for a powerful enough desktop PC would do.

Comment: Thanks for the thread, Tyberius, really helped. I guess I just need some recommendations based on the budget I mentioned above.

Comment: @tumblewush The answers in the other thread will also apply to you. A powerful desktop PC for 2-3 people will be cheaper than a laptop with the same specs, but since you want something for 2-3 people rather than for 1 person, you'll want something more expensive, so the two will even out and the final price can easily be made to fit within the rather large range of 3k to 5k. Much effort will be needed on your part to find the best deal for 32/64GB of RAM or 2TB of 2TB of HDD space. Prices will vary significantly based on where you live, so we can't provide answers better than already given.